# Confirmation Modal After Every click. Works first time, then fails. (Modal on Modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to launch a selection modal, then a form modal and finally a confirmation modal after user's click send.

This works fine the very first time, however after that, confirmation modal does not pop up, and it just simply exits.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chooseModal">Open</button>

<!-- Select One Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="chooseModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select An Option</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myForm">Click to Email</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chooseModal">Click to Do Something Else</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<!-- Email Form Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Email</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="emailInput">
                <h4>To:</h4>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h4>Subject:</h4>
                <input type="text" value="subject" name="emailSubject" id="emailSubject"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h4>Body:</h4>
                <textarea rows="4" id="emailBody"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <button onclick="confirmAlert()" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myForm">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Confirmation Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="PDFconfirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank You!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>Your message has been sent.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function confirmAlert(){ 

    $(".modal, .modal-backdrop").hide();

    $('#PDFconfirmation').modal('show');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#PDFconfirmation, .modal, .modal-backdrop").hide();
    }, 2000);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, however I forgot to add the initial modal. So in all, there will be a modal, then another modal, then the confirmation modal. I've updated my original post. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your JS code to this:

```
function confirmAlert(){ 

  $("#chooseModal").modal('hide');

  $('#PDFconfirmation').modal('show');

  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#PDFconfirmation").modal('hide');
  }, 2000);

}
```

However, you can improve this code but now you have a better idea how you should toggle (show/hide) modals to prevent this sort of bugs.

Comment: Thanks, however I forgot to add the initial modal. So in all, there will be a modal, then another modal, then the confirmation modal. I've updated my original post. thanks!!

Comment: Thanks! so simple. I guess I was stuck on hiding all modals and modal-backdrops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet,

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myForm">Open</button>

<!-- PDF Share Form Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Email</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="emailInput">
                <h4>To:</h4>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h4>Subject:</h4>
                <input type="text" value="subject" name="emailSubject" id="emailSubject"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h4>Body:</h4>
                <textarea rows="4" id="emailBody"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PDFconfirmation">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Confirmation Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="PDFconfirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank You!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>Your message has been sent.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```